# How to upload a multiple set of images to database at once using php

Tags: javascript, php

I impliment code to upload set of information to database from excel/CSV except image file.

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $data1 = data[0];
  $data2 = data[1];
  $data3 = data[2];

  $sql = "INSERT INTO tblName VALUES ('$data1','$data2','$data2')";
  $conn->query($sql);
}
```

It may be upload 100 of data to database. How could I upload that amount of images(relevent to the above data) to database.

Comment: What you tried so far? What problem you facing?

Comment: none of my business but make one large query and then insert it one time.
note : not related to question :P

Comment: I want to upload data to my database using CSV file. I want to upload images for relevent data of that CSV files. (It is ok, if there is a methord to upload images through CSV file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We only stores the path of the image or file into db. 
So You have upload to pass the full of your images into the csv in each row. and the first you have to upload the image on your server and then take that path and store it in db. or if the images are already on the server. you can directly save their path.

```
$handle = fopen($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], "r");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
  $data1 = data[0];
  $data2 = data[1];
  $data3 = data[2];
  $data3 = data[3]; // assuming this the url


  $sql = "INSERT INTO tblName VALUES     ('$data1','$data2','$data2','$data3')";
  $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE` sql query to import csv file

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'Full path of csv file'
INTO TABLE "table_name"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
(column_1, column_2, column3 ...);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. but how can i upload set of image files to database(Using CSV file or another way)

Comment: storing image in database is a bad practice. It will be better if you upload all the images on server using FTP client and follow rest of the steps mentioned by @Sudhanshu Jain